# How to set position sorting to be default

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting, position

I can see how to set the position of products in a category however what I can't see is how to set the default sorting order[image]

The only options I have is "Best Value", "Name" & "Price:. The sort by of position is not avaiable

Please could someone advise how I set the sort by to be "Position" by default

Answer (score 0):

"Best Value" actually sorts by position. If you try editing the position values of the products in a category, you should see the desired result.

I believe it was named like this for marketing reasons, so you can put your desired products to appear at the top of a category, and the customer will think it's the "best value" product.